# Increase Asp.net Application Performance

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, web

I just want some tricks for increase ASP.Net application. This question is a little wide, but if you can give me some general tips I will appreciate.

Comment: Why Do You Capitalize the First Letter of Each Word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this booK: [http://www.amazon.com/Ultra-Fast-ASP-NET-Build-Ultra-Scalable-Server/dp/1430223839/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1289574343&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223839)

Comment: +1 Best (probably the only) book around on this. Also check out Steve Souders' two books: http://stevesouders.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you don't go into premature optimization.

Figure out what the slow parts are, then fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling automatic Viewstate management is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

Optimising your database:
 * redesign/normalise your schema
 * index tables
 * revisit your SQL/Stored Proc code and amend for speed if you can.
 * Check execution plans for big datasets and indeed dodgy SQL code ;)

Web App:
Use Tracing to figure out where the bottlenecks are and then:
 * Cache the output, controls and data wherever possible.
 * Use IIS to compress the html output.
 * Compress or disable viewstate entirely for webforms. Or persist it in a db.

Misc
 * Load external files from CDNs e.g. jquery
 * Run a tool to strip whitespace from the html of the response.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid using the view state if you can
2. If you can do CRUD operations through web service methods or web page methods, go for it (this will avoid full post backs and going back and forth of viewstate)
3. If ViewState is a must, try using one of the ViewState providers or implement your own
4. If using javascript libraries or your own code, try minimizing them with jsmin (http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)
5. Use compression on IIS or Apache (if you use Mono)
6. Use Caching for images and javascript files (configure IIS or Apache to send the appropriate headers when getting data from the "images" or "js" folders on your solution)
7. Define image sizes on your markup i.e. set width="..." height="..."

Comment: #7 doesn't help performance at all.  If you link to a 5MB image in the markup, the full 5MB still have to be pulled down to the client no matter if you want it as the regular size or 100x100px.

Comment: Oh yes, it does help optimizing browser rendering. http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html